# 22.04 wifi lost on a aorus trx40 pro wifi

Tags: networking, drivers, 22.04, network-manager, iwlwifi

Hello I have a wifi problem. On 22.04 Ubuntu it does not see the wifi anymore. I think it may be a driver issue. Under windows there is no problem and I have had this setup for years before when I was using Ubuntu 20.04.

This is my network setting

```
'''bgood@bgood-ryzen ~> sudo lshw -class network (base)
[sudo] Mot de passe de bgood :
*-network
description: Ethernet interface
produit: I211 Gigabit Network Connection
fabricant: Intel Corporation
identifiant matériel: 0
information bus: pci@0000:44:00.0
nom logique: enp68s0
version: 03
numéro de série: b4:2e:99:a8:6b:83
taille: 1Gbit/s
capacité: 1Gbit/s
bits: 32 bits
horloge: 33MHz
fonctionnalités: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
configuration : autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igb driverversion=5.15.0-58-generic duplex=full firmware=0. 6-1 ip=192.168.1.92 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
ressources : irq:51 mémoire:d6600000-d661ffff portE/S:9000(taille=32) mémoire:d6620000-d6623fff
*-network
description: Network controller
produit: Wi-Fi 6 AX200
fabricant: Intel Corporation
identifiant matériel: 0
information bus: pci@0000:45:00.0
version: 1a
bits: 64 bits
horloge: 33MHz
fonctionnalités: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
configuration : driver=iwlwifi latency=0
ressources : irq:51 mémoire:d6500000-d6503fff'''
```

there is my output with the last command
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Etdq.png

i don't understand how to post code so i edit my message

```
[    9.311427] iwlwifi 0000:45:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    9.345702] iwlwifi 0000:45:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[    9.345720] iwlwifi 0000:45:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 89.3.35.37
[    9.346365] iwlwifi 0000:45:00.0: loaded firmware version 66.f1c864e0.0 cc-a0-66.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    9.782396] iwlwifi 0000:45:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
[    9.907553] iwlwifi 0000:45:00.0: Detected RF HR B3, rfid=0x10a100
[    9.972403] iwlwifi 0000:45:00.0: base HW address: 50:eb:71:10:f2:6b
[    9.989291] iwlwifi 0000:45:00.0 wlo2: renamed from wlan0
```

28 days later i have this

bgood@bgood-ryzen ~> sudo dmesg | grep iwl                               (base)
[sudo] Mot de passe de bgood :
[    8.853345] iwlwifi 0000:45:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    8.889081] iwlwifi 0000:45:00.0: CSR_RESET = 0x10
[    8.889238] iwlwifi 0000:45:00.0: Host monitor block 0x0 vector 0x0
[    8.889307] iwlwifi 0000:45:00.0:     value [iter 0]: 0x3f7f8830
[    8.889420] iwlwifi 0000:45:00.0:     value [iter 1]: 0x3f7f0430
[    8.889509] iwlwifi 0000:45:00.0:     value [iter 2]: 0x3f7f0c30
[    8.889578] iwlwifi 0000:45:00.0:     value [iter 3]: 0x3f7f0830
[    8.889678] iwlwifi 0000:45:00.0:     value [iter 4]: 0x3f7f0830
[    8.889775] iwlwifi 0000:45:00.0:     value [iter 5]: 0x3f7f0c30
[    8.889860] iwlwifi 0000:45:00.0:     value [iter 6]: 0x3f7f8030
[    8.889967] iwlwifi 0000:45:00.0:     value [iter 7]: 0x3f7f0430
[    8.890014] iwlwifi 0000:45:00.0:     value [iter 8]: 0x3f7f0830
[    8.890084] iwlwifi 0000:45:00.0:     value [iter 9]: 0x3f7f8430
[    8.890152] iwlwifi 0000:45:00.0:     value [iter 10]: 0x3f7f0030
[    8.890221] iwlwifi 0000:45:00.0:     value [iter 11]: 0x3f7f0830
[    8.890302] iwlwifi 0000:45:00.0:     value [iter 12]: 0x3f7f0430
[    8.890359] iwlwifi 0000:45:00.0:     value [iter 13]: 0x3f7f0c30
[    8.890421] iwlwifi 0000:45:00.0:     value [iter 14]: 0x3f7f0c30
[    8.890473] iwlwifi 0000:45:00.0: Host monitor block 0x0 vector 0x1
[    8.890493] iwlwifi 0000:45:00.0:     value [iter 0]: 0x044466c2
[    8.890505] iwlwifi 0000:45:00.0:     value [iter 1]: 0x044466c2
[    8.890516] iwlwifi 0000:45:00.0:     value [iter 2]: 0x044466c2
[    8.890526] iwlwifi 0000:45:00.0:     value [iter 3]: 0x044466c2
[    8.890767] iwlwifi 0000:45:00.0:     value [iter 4]: 0x044466c2
[    8.891011] iwlwifi 0000:45:00.0:     value [iter 5]: 0x044466c2
[    8.891231] iwlwifi 0000:45:00.0:     value [iter 6]: 0x044466c2
[    8.891444] iwlwifi 0000:45:00.0:     value [iter 7]: 0x044466c2
[    8.891763] iwlwifi 0000:45:00.0:     value [iter 8]: 0x044466c2
[    8.892312] iwlwifi 0000:45:00.0:     value [iter 9]: 0x044466c2
[    8.892513] iwlwifi 0000:45:00.0:     value [iter 10]: 0x044466c2
[    8.892707] iwlwifi 0000:45:00.0:     value [iter 11]: 0x044466c2
[    8.892887] iwlwifi 0000:45:00.0:     value [iter 12]: 0x044466c2
[    8.893071] iwlwifi 0000:45:00.0:     value [iter 13]: 0x044466c2
[    8.893239] iwlwifi 0000:45:00.0:     value [iter 14]: 0x044466c2
[    8.893397] iwlwifi 0000:45:00.0: Host monitor block 0x0 vector 0x6
[    8.893558] iwlwifi 0000:45:00.0:     value [iter 0]: 0xb00c4471
[    8.893714] iwlwifi 0000:45:00.0:     value [iter 1]: 0xf00c4471
[    8.893863] iwlwifi 0000:45:00.0:     value [iter 2]: 0xf00c4471
[    8.894007] iwlwifi 0000:45:00.0:     value [iter 3]: 0xe00c4471
[    8.894145] iwlwifi 0000:45:00.0:     value [iter 4]: 0xb00c4471
[    8.894315] iwlwifi 0000:45:00.0:     value [iter 5]: 0xe00c4471
[    8.894564] iwlwifi 0000:45:00.0:     value [iter 6]: 0xb00c4471
[    8.894859] iwlwifi 0000:45:00.0:     value [iter 7]: 0xe00c4471
[    8.894973] iwlwifi 0000:45:00.0:     value [iter 8]: 0xe00c4471
[    8.895080] iwlwifi 0000:45:00.0:     value [iter 9]: 0xf00c4471
[    8.895182] iwlwifi 0000:45:00.0:     value [iter 10]: 0xf00c4471
[    8.895277] iwlwifi 0000:45:00.0:     value [iter 11]: 0xb00c4471
[    8.895366] iwlwifi 0000:45:00.0:     value [iter 12]: 0xf00c4471
[    8.895451] iwlwifi 0000:45:00.0:     value [iter 13]: 0xf00c4471
[    8.895529] iwlwifi 0000:45:00.0:     value [iter 14]: 0xa00c4471
[    8.895606] iwlwifi 0000:45:00.0: Host monitor block 0x22 vector 0x0
[    8.895685] iwlwifi 0000:45:00.0:     value [iter 0]: 0x00000000
[    8.896025] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:45:00.0 failed with error -110
bgood@bgood-ryzen ~>                                                     (base)

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `sudo dmesg | grep iwl` If the output is lengthy, paste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Since there was no response, let's try harder: `sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi && sufo modprobe iwlwifi && sudo dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: Hello today my wifi is back again and i dont know why

Comment: Is there anything interesting in the message log? `sudo dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: i've edited my post

Comment: Looks perfect. We need to see the message log when the wifi is *not* working.

Comment: Please turn off Fast Boot in Windows: https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#about_dual-boot_with_windows_and_fast-boot_enabled

Comment: its ok now thanks